# Can't install django-mailgun

Tags: django, pip, django-mailgun

I want to install `django-mailgun` library. Followed this tutorial https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-send-email-using-mailgun-api-94/

I tried
 `pip install django-mailgun --verbose`

**Log of command:**

```
Using pip 21.0.1 from /home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r4kdc56j
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-s1r35ye8
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-s1r35ye8
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-s1r35ye8
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-s1r35ye8
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-14dd83we
1 location(s) to search for versions of django-mailgun:
* https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/django-mailgun/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13
Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/django-mailgun/ - skipping
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'django-mailgun': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-mailgun
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-mailgun
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name]
KeyError: 'django-mailgun'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 83, in from_requirement
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('django-mailgun')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 320, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('django-mailgun'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    six.raise_from(error, e)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for django-mailgun
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-wgh79mc3'
```

OS -- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: [pip install django-mailgun-provider](https://pypi.org/project/django-mailgun-provider/) or  [pip install django-mailgun-mime](https://pypi.org/project/django-mailgun-mime/)

Comment: Thank you, but what is the problem with my pip install command?

Comment: No any problem in your pip command.Here no any version found of `django-mailgun` and you face big error because you written `--verbose` at the end of `pip` command.it means give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

That command is wrong, you need to follow the official command: pip install django-mailgun-mime